# How to get class name as string?

Tags: haxe

How would I get the class name in string?

I tried this:

```
Type.getClassName(this));
```

Where this is the current class I am in, but I got error:

```
com.SubWidget should be Class<Dynamic>
```

Any help?

Comment: `this.getClass().getName()`

Comment: @alfasin it should be noted that that only works if you have "using Type;" in the imports at the top of your file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should pass a `Class` to `Type.getClassName`. So, first grab that using `Type.getClass`, like this:

http://try.haxe.org/#6A196

```
class Test {
    static function main() new Test();

    function new()
    {
        var className = Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(this));
        trace('Current class name = $className');
    }
}
```

Also see: http://api.haxe.org/Type.html#getClassName